# JPA EntityManager find by parent id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following two classes:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Benefit extends WorkflowEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "benefit_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "benefit_sequence", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "benefit_id", nullable = false)
    @AuditJoinTable(name = "aud_benefit_benefit_offering")
    private Set<BenefitOffering> offerings = emptySet();
```

and

```
@Entity

public class BenefitOffering {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "benefit_offering_sequence", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "benefit_offering_id")
    private Long id;

    ... (there is no reference back to the Benefit in this class)
```

Making `offerings` EAGER loaded in `Benefit` is not an option as it'll slow the system down.

So typically `offerings` are not loaded for a `benefit`, and I have to retrieve these separately.

I know that I can do something like this to retrieve an entity by its id

```
Benefit benefit = entityManager.find(Benefit.class, benefitId);
```

Is there a way to retrieve all `Offerings` belonging to a given `Benefit` using `entityManager`?

Comment: You can use a query. Do you know how to use them?

Comment: I'm digging into it now - looks like you're right, queries is a way forward!